# Ignore uncovered line with SonarQube and Cobertura

Tags: junit, sonarqube, cobertura

I am using sonar with Cobertura and a have some classes like this:

[image: uncovered annotation]

How can I make SonarQube/Cobertura to ignore this annotation? I am testing the class, but not in the server context.

I tried the `// NOSONAR` but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible to tell SonarQube to ignore this annotation. You might wanna try with JaCoCo coverage engine, maybe it will give better results (?).

Comment: With jacoco I got a coverage problem with a method that was throwing an exception. it looks like an expected behavior.